# How can I add a button to my FormControls without getting an error?

Tags: angular

I have a really simple Form that looks like this in my component

```
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      endTime: new FormControl(this.dateToTime(date), [afterCurrentTime(0, 0)])
    });
}
```

And in my template

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="startSession()">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        id="tenantInput"
        type="time"
        matInput
        [placeholder]="getTranslateKey('endTime' + '.label') | translate"
        [formControl]="form.controls['endTime']"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
    <div
      *ngIf="
        form.controls['endTime'].invalid &&
        (form.controls['endTime'].dirty || form.controls['endTime'].touched)
      "
      class="alert alert-danger"
    >
      <div
        *ngIf="form.controls['endTime'].errors"
        style="color: #fc0d0d; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: 8px; font-size: 11px;">
        {{getTranslateKey("endTime." +"errors." +getControlErrorKey(form.controls["endTime"])) | translate}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm simply trying to add a FormControl to the form so that I can see the state of the submit button and whether it is disabled or enabled.

I've tried this

```
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      endTime: new FormControl(this.dateToTime(date), [afterCurrentTime(0, 0)]),
      submitButton: new FormControl()
    });
```

and then adding

```
[formControl]="form.controls['startSessionButton']"
```

to my button, but this just gives me this error

`Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute`

Comment: Why are you adding formControl to button? any specific reason ? .... form control is not buttons attribute that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: @MaBbKhawaja I want to be able to subscribe to the valueChanges of a button so that I can see when a button has changed state from disabled to enabled

Comment: @Jake12342134 could you reproduce a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example?

Comment: Use mutation observer to listen attribute changes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 1):

You can't mark a button as formControl, in your case maybe you can set disabled attribute of your button equal to a boolean property declared in the component. In this way you'll always know whether your button is disabled or not.

```
<button color="primary" [disabled]="someProperty" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use formControl on button,

Form control is for inputs.

Just have a button element in your html and set the type to submit like this :

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

Comment: But then how can I see whether or not a button is enabled or disabled?

Comment: it's not possible with formControl you can use another ways like binding a variable to "[disabled]" attribute.

Comment: I don't want to set the button disabled, I've already done that. I want to know WHEN the button has been set to disabled.

Comment: @Jake12342134 you can do this by js or angular methods.